# "Insertbefore" function in html

Tags: javascript, html, function

I need to use the 'insertbefore' function to add new words in an ordered list, but don't know how to change the predefined word "water" to any optional word.

**Code**

```
function myFunction() {
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("water");
    newItem.appendChild(textnode);

    var list = document.getElementById("Course registration");
    list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a name to the textbox you could do the below. Note that this answer doesn't take the ordering into account, just the insert.

```
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
 <input name="txtboxName" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add a task here">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
</div>

<ol id="Course registration">
  <li>Register to full Stack Web Course</li>
  <li>Attend Selection Day</li>
  <li>Go see X-Men apocalypse movie</li>
</ol>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var newItem = document.createElement("li");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementsByName('txtboxName')[0].value);
    newItem.appendChild(textnode);

    var list = document.getElementById("Course registration");
    list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!
But then it adds the word-undefined.
Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/YairB/p95b8wmz/1/

Comment: Are you passing in the value? eg onclick="myFunction('add')"

Comment: Yes. <button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

Comment: Try the above answer now. You will need to put a name on the textbox as well.

Comment: Same problem- when i enter any text in the box, it adds 'undefined' instead the text i entered:

https://jsfiddle.net/YairB/p95b8wmz/2/

Comment: Did you add the name attribute to the textbox? Eg  <input name="txtboxName" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Add a task here">

Comment: I have added the full jsfiddle version to the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot anyway,,,, i'll hand it like it is, and hope for the best :)

Comment: No way :) Lets get it working. My solution works. You're so close.

Comment: No problem, thanks. Good luck with your course work.